Converting dict to dataclass type dynamically, and an instance back to a dict, results in empty dict
Have a nested dictionary.
stock_price = {'lastPrice': 129.1,
    'open': 126.57,
    'close': 0,
    'intraDayHighLow': {'min': 126.4, 'max': 129.55, 'value': 129.1},
    'weekHighLow': {'min': 49.7, 'minDate': '26-Jun-2023', 
       'max': 142.9,
       'maxDate': '30-Apr-2024',
        'value': 129.1},
    }

...which is converted to a dataclass, as follows.
from dataclasses import dataclass
def create_dataclass_from_dict(data_dict: dict, class_name:str):

    fields = {}
    
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            nested_class_name = key.capitalize()
            nested_class = create_dataclass_from_dict(value, class_name=nested_class_name)
            fields[key] = nested_class
        else:
            fields[key] = value
    
    return dataclass(type(class_name, (), fields))

....but when I see the dict of the instance, it shows an empty dictionary...
Stock = create_dataclass_from_dict(stock_price, 'Stock')

my_stock = Stock()
my_stock.weekHighLow.minDate # gives '26-Jun-2023' as intended. Want this!!

my_stock.__dict__ # gives {}

...and so not able to convert it back to a dictionary using the following code:
import json
def to_dict(obj):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(obj, default=lambda o: o.__dict__))

to_dict(my_stock) # gives {}

Where am I going wrong? Why is the .__dict__ empty?

Creating the dataclass, why is __dict__ empty

type(class_name, (), fields)


This creates a class which has fields as class attributes. They will be present in Stock.__dict__, but not in my_stock.__dict__ for any instance my_stock of Stock.

my_stock.weekHighLow.minDate 


This works, because if an attribute is not found in an instance of a class, it is looked up in the class object next.
Using dataclass() with a class created like this will not actually create the dataclass fields.
For example, dataclass("Stock", (), {"last_price": 129.1}) is like writing
@dataclass
class Stock:
    last_price = 129.1

but a dataclass field requires a type annotation, like
@dataclass
class Stock:
    last_price: float = 129.1

which would create a field called last_price with a default value 129.1.
To create a dataclass dynamically, use dataclasses.make_dataclass instead.
In your case, you would have to replace

fields = {}
# ...
fields[key] = nested_class
# ...
fields[key] = value
# ...
return dataclass(type(class_name, (), fields))


by
fields = []
# ...
fields.append((key, nested_class, field(default_factory=nested_class)))
# ...
fields.append((key, type(value), field(default=value)))
# ...
return make_dataclass(class_name, fields)

(using dataclasses.field as field)
Converting a dataclass instance to a dictionary
To convert a dataclass instance (assuming the dataclass has been created properly) to a dictionary, you should use dataclasses.asdict, not rely on the __dict__ attribute.
This is explained in more detail in this answer.

For the sake of closure, here is the corrected code:
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, field, asdict

# the dict
stock_price = {'lastPrice': 129.1,
    'open': 126.57,
    'close': 0,
    'intraDayHighLow': {'min': 126.4, 'max': 129.55, 'value': 129.1},
    'weekHighLow': {'min': 49.7, 'minDate': '26-Jun-2023', 
       'max': 142.9,
       'maxDate': '30-Apr-2024',
        'value': 129.1},
    }

# dynamic dataclass constructor
def create_dataclass_from_dict(data_dict: dict, class_name:str):

    fields = []
    
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            nested_class_name = key.capitalize()
            nested_class = create_dataclass_from_dict(value, class_name=nested_class_name)
            fields.append((key, nested_class, field(default_factory=nested_class)))
        else:
            fields.append((key, type(value), field(default=value)))
    
    return make_dataclass(class_name, fields)

# instantiate
Stock = create_dataclass_from_dict(stock_price, 'Stock')
my_stock = Stock()

# check nested
print(my_stock.weekHighLow.minDate) # works '26-Jun-2023'

# Reconstruct to dict
print(asdict(my_stock))


